# aiogram как получить file_id с callback_query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Всех приветствую! Как получить file_id "photo", из следующего словаря?:

```
{"id": "3382238453917682797", "from": {"id": 543894483, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Mimdc", "username": "fjnfkerklewe", "language_code": "ru"}, "message": {"message_id": 852, "from": {"id": 6534353424, "is_bot": true, "first_name": "Проверочный бот", "username": "provboter_bot"}, "chat": {"id": 54342345, "first_name": "Mimdc", "username": "fjnfkerklewe", "type": "private"}, "date": 1646056959, "photo": [{"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIDVGIc1f9SgiDpDxm962Y4lRRACHJ9AAL6uDEblxnhSIJIaehVrKVBAQADAgADcwADIwQ", "file_unique_id": "AQAD-rgxG5cZ4Uh4", "file_size": 653, "width": 43, "height": 90}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIDVGIc1f9SgiDpDxm962Y4lRRACHJ9AAL6uDEblxnhSIJIaehVrKVBAQADAgADbQADIwQ", "file_unique_id": "AQAD-rgxG5cZ4Uhy", "file_size": 5390, "width": 152, "height": 320}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIDVGIc1f9SgiDpDxm962Y4lRRACHJ9AAL6uDEblxnhSIJIaehVrKVBAQADAgADeAADIwQ", "file_unique_id": "AQAD-rgxG5cZ4Uh9", "file_size": 19317, "width": 379, "height": 800}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIDVGIc1f9SgiDpDxm962Y4lRRACHJ9AAL6uDEblxnhSIJIaehVrKVBAQADAgADeQADIwQ", "file_unique_id": "AQAD-rgxG5cZ4Uh-", "file_size": 30390, "width": 606, "height": 1280}], "caption": "\n------\n\nVhuuhv", "reply_markup": {"inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "Да", "callback_data": "object_addphoto_881401930"}], [{"text": "Нет", "callback_data": "object_remove_881401930"}]]}}, "chat_instance": "-3466429663041482177", "data": "object_addphoto_881401930"}
```

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda event: event.data.startswith('object_addphoto_'))
async def object_add_none_img(event: types.callback_query.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await event.message.delete()
    await state.finish()

    obj_user_id = str(event.data).replace('textobject_addphoto__add_','')
    obj_user_name = str(event.message.caption).split('\n------\n\n')[0]
    obj_user_message = str(event.message.caption).split('\n------\n\n')[1]
    obj_img = str(event.photo[-1].file_id)

    await state.update_data(o_id = obj_user_id)
    await state.update_data(o_name = obj_user_name)
    await state.update_data(o_message = obj_user_message)
    await state.update_data(o_img = obj_img)
```

event.photo[-1].file_id выдаёт ошибку (callback всегда идёт с фотографией)

Comment: Выложите код своего обработчика, чтобы Вам могли помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к объекту `CallbackQuery`, но данные сообщения лежат в объекте `Message`.

Вместо `event.photo[-1].file_id` используйте `event.message.photo[-1].file_id`